# fill_between always below plot lines

Tags: python, matplotlib

Hi I am using fill_between command in python, but it seems that the fill_between is always below the line plots.

See this example, the alpha=1, so it is not invisible. All the lines should not be seen when they are in the fill_between location. But I still see them.

iptyhon --pylab

```
plot([0,1],[1,1],'r')
plot([0,1],[2,2],'g')
plot([0,1],[0.5,0.5],'b')
plot([0,1],[3,3],'k')

fill_between([0,0.25],[0,3.5],facecolor='LightGreen')
fill_between([0.3,0.45],[0,3.5],facecolor='Salmon')
fill_between([0.5,0.7],[0,3.5],facecolor='LightBlue')
fill_between([0.75,0.95],[0,3.5],facecolor='LightYellow')
```

[image]

When I use alpha = 0.5 I still get something that is not correct, the correct behavior is that each line will change is color when it is in the same location as the fill_between, but you see the color of the lines does not change...

```
plot([0,1],[1,1],'r')
plot([0,1],[2,2],'g')
plot([0,1],[0.5,0.5],'b')
plot([0,1],[3,3],'k')

fill_between([0,0.25],[0,3.5],facecolor='LightGreen',alpha=0.5)
fill_between([0.3,0.45],[0,3.5],facecolor='Salmon',alpha=0.5)
fill_between([0.5,0.7],[0,3.5],facecolor='LightBlue',alpha=0.5)
fill_between([0.75,0.95],[0,3.5],facecolor='LightYellow',alpha=0.5)
```

[image]

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can fix this using the `zorder` kwarg:

```
plot([0,1],[1,1],'r',zorder=1)
plot([0,1],[2,2],'g',zorder=1)
plot([0,1],[0.5,0.5],'b',zorder=1)
plot([0,1],[3,3],'k',zorder=1)

fill_between([0,0.25],[0,3.5],facecolor='LightGreen',zorder=2)
fill_between([0.3,0.45],[0,3.5],facecolor='Salmon',zorder=2)
fill_between([0.5,0.7],[0,3.5],facecolor='LightBlue',zorder=2)
fill_between([0.75,0.95],[0,3.5],facecolor='LightYellow',zorder=2)
```

[image]

Comment: Hi thanks, it helps, but why isn't it automatically organized? as in plots, when each plot as a higher zvalue as the plots before it?

Comment: @Oren Different matplotlib objects (e.g. lines, shapes) have different default zorders, regardless of the order in which you plot them

Comment: It is not quite that they have different zorders, it is that the drawing of elements with identical zorder is not defined.  The current implementation is that they are grouped by type (in a fixed order) and then by the order they were added.  The former is due to the internal storage of the artists in the axes (which might change in the future) and the later by the fact that python's sort is stable.